# How to configure release pipeline approval to be able to approve 2 stages in a row by the same person?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have two stages in my release pipeline. Both requires pre-deployment approval. Stage can be approved by anybody from a group. When I approve first stage I can't approve the next one and I have this message:

> Waiting for all approvers to approve in sequence .

Is this possible to configure approval in that way so the same person from the group can approve both stages? Or I need to change my pipeline and use `Manual Intervention` task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have specified multiple approvers and set `Approval order` to `In sequence` in the pre-deployment approvals settings.

> When we specified multiple approvers, **all users must approve the deployment**. If a
> group is added, one user in the group must approve the deployment.

In this case we have to wait for all approvers to approve in sequence. That means if someone else is in front of you, you must wait for his approval before you can approve. It's not possible to skip.

[image]

However we can set the `Approval order` to `Any order` or `Any one user`, thus you can approve the stage2. (You may need to wait for a while before the `Approve` button is activated.)

[image]

Comment: It makes totally sense that this is not available when you have one person provided. But why this doesn't appear when group is given. However, this solves my issue. Thanks a lot Andy!